# Convert list of JPEGs to repeating animated gif using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, gif, animated-gif

I am using the `convert` command in [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org) to convert a list of JPEGs to one single animated GIF. The problem comes when the first frame keeps on repeating after every second within the gif which messes it all up.

#### Command:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 " + directoryname + "\\*.jpg " + directoryname + "\\output.gif
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! You'll probably have better luck with the question on [su], our site for the general use of computing software. Stack Overflow's mostly for questions relating to programming using actual code -- the Stack Overflow community generally [don't consider using tools via the command line interface as programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168740/are-ffmpeg-questions-really-off-topic). Thanks for asking -- good luck!

Comment: Your question can be voted/flagged for migration to [su].

Comment: Should this not be tagged `imagemgick` rather than `ffmpeg`?